# XPath expression with predicats and conditions

Tags: xml, xpath

Where is the mistake in my XPath expresstion? I need to retrieve the profiles of all users for which all uploaded videos have an average rating greater than or equal to 3.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smileyvideo>
   <video id="8628149">
      <uploader>satsuya.oda@example.com</uploader>
      <title>Bad Apple</title>
      <ratings>
         <rating user="epwager@example.com" value="1" />
         <rating user="ajenk@example.com" value="2" />
      </ratings>
   </video>
   <video id="123456">
      <uploader>ajenk@example.com</uploader>
      <title>Musician Cat</title>
      <ratings>
         <rating user="satsuya.oda@example.com" value="3" />
         <rating user="epwager@example.com" value="3" />
         <rating user="ajenk@example.com" value="4" />
      </ratings>
   </video>
   <video id="474920">
      <uploader>satsuya.oda@example.com</uploader>
      <title>Shrek</title>
      <ratings>
         <rating user="epwager@example.com" value="1" />
         <rating user="ajenk@example.com" value="1" />
      </ratings>
   </video>
   <!-- Users List -->
   <user>
      <name>Emil P. Wager</name>
      <email>epwager@example.com</email>
   </user>
   <user>
      <name>Satsuya Oda</name>
      <email>satsuya.oda@example.com</email>
   </user>
   <user>
      <name>Anthony J. Jenkins</name>
      <email>ajenk@example.com</email>
      <bio>I am a food scientist, currently working in iceland. Make sure to
check out my blog!</bio>
   </user>
</smileyvideo>
```

My XPath expression is

```
//user[preceding-sibling::video/uploader[avg((following-sibling::ratings/rating/@value))>=3]/text()=//user/email/text()]
```

Comment: what version of xpath? I doubt this can be done using xpath 1.0 ..

Comment: yes, XPath 1.0 does not support even functions, I think, I use XPath 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `avg()` function in XPath 1.0 (which I suspect you use here).

Try this:

```
//video[sum(ratings/rating/@value) div count(ratings/rating) >= 3]/uploader
```

Or, a slightly shorter variant:

```
//video[ratings[sum(rating/@value) div count(rating) >= 3]]/uploader
```

---

To go from there to a list of `<user>` objects is trivial:

```
//user[email = //video[ratings[sum(rating/@value) div count(rating) >= 3]]/uploader]
```

---

Or, when `avg()` is available as a function because you use XPath 2.0+, the even shorter:

```
//user[email = //video[avg(ratings/rating/@value) >= 3]/uploader]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Tomalak! But I use XPath 2.0 and I must use avg, which we studied on the lectures. I tried the expression 

//video[uploader[avg((following-sibling::ratings/rating/@value))>=3]/text()=//user/email/text()]

and it works right

Comment: Use what works. If `avg()` is available, use it. That does not change anything about my answer (except that the expressions will get *even* shorter). Your post did not include what XPath version you use, and I'm not a clairvoyant. Next time please include the version of the software you are working with. As a general tip I would discourage using the axes (`following-sibling` etc) for this kind of task.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I found out that my expression did not work properly because of //user before email/text()
Could you explain, if it is not difficult for you, why? I'm confused, because in expression for video retrieving, which I wrote in the previous comment, the same condition worked properly...

Comment: Yes. Your original expression reads as follows: *"select any user where [the uploader of a 3+ video = any user email]"*, so this selects all users as soon as there is at least one 3+ video. What you wanted to express is *"select any user where [the uploader of a 3+ video = this user's email]"* - and that's exactly what you get when you leave off the `//user`.